# How to get absolute pyc file path with python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, path, pyc

How can we get the compiled python pyc file path with python 3.x in the current environment? I know it's in the `__pycache__` direcotry, but I couldn't find a way to find the file path. Because the names of pyc files of python 3 changes by the environment.

Comment: I'd like to get the modified date of the pyc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you know the path to the source (ie `.py`) file, there's a function [`importlib.util.cache_from_source`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.cache_from_source) that does exactly what you want. For example, to get the `.pyc` file corresponding to the `numpy` package, you would do:

```
import importlib
import numpy

importlib.util.cache_from_source(numpy.__file__)
```

For me (on OS X), this prints out something along the lines of:

```
/<absolute path to site-packages>/numpy/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
```